# isset function not working on same page as form

Tags: php, forms, isset

When I use the `isset()` function when data is posted from another PHP page it works fine.
But when I use the `isset()` function in the same page to process a form it does not post the 
data. I see the data in the url but the `isset()` does not seem to work. The form stays empty and nothing happens.

Here is the form I am currently working on:

```
<h3>Register</h3>

<?php 
   if(isset($_POST["register_email"],$_POST["register_name"],$_POST["register_password"]))      
   {
       $register_email=$_POST['register_email'];
       $register_name=$_POST['register_name'];
       $register_password=$_POST['register_password'];

       $errors=array();

       if(empty($register_email) || empty($register_name) || empty($register_password))
       {
           $errors[]='All fields required';
       } 

       if(!empty($errors))
       {
           foreach($errors as $error)
           {
               echo $error,'<br />';
           }
       } 
       else {
           echo 'ok';
       }
   }
?>

<form action="" method="">
    <p>Email: <br /><input type="email" name="register_email" size="35" maxlength="255"></p>
    <p>Full name: <br /><input type="text" name="register_name" maxlength="35"></p>
    <p>Password: <br /><input type="password" name="register_password" maxlength="35"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Register"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form first?

Comment: 1. Did you submit the form?
2. Did you try to use URL parameters? It requires `$_GET`, not `$_POST`

Comment: To clarify what Nadav S is saying, if you are passing the parameters through the URL, then you would access them through $_GET.  However, you can still use $_POST, you just have to submit the form first.

Comment: You might want to use `$_REQUEST` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php which contains the union of GET+POST+COOKIES. If you are brave: http://devlog.info/2010/02/04/why-php-request-array-is-dangerous/

Comment: You are missing method="post" in your form, that'll do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have forgotten to set the form's method to post:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Comment: yesss! awww! i missed the post in the method. now its working. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

In case of mine,just set for one only,in this case the name of input to register and isset to register.isset will refer to the name of input

`if(isset($_POST["register"]))`
`input type="submit" value="Register" name="register">`